# formidable.IncomingForm upload a pictures without setting the headers so soon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, formidable

How do I use 
https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable

upload the file on Nodejs and not set the headers so soon?

```
router.post('/upload/pictures', function (req, res, next) {

var temp_path =  '';
var temp_token =  '';
var new_location = '';
var file_name = '';
var sessionKey = '';


var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    files = [],
    fields = [];

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
```

???? res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));

```
  form.on('end', function(fields, files) {

    /!* Temporary location of our uploaded file *!/
     temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    /!* The file name of the uploaded file *!/
     file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
    /!* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file *!/
```

I check for a session and set the headers here.. then get an error.

if (!result) return res.status(401).send({message: 'Session expired'});

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:690:11)

Also, How do I get rid of all the temporary files it creates??

```
  vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp$ ls
     upload_1a6db52f44333bcc0c186d326f130187 
     upload_77e40c1d9a779cd78e3dd99f67e041c7
     upload_77e40c1d9a779cd78e3dd99f67e041c7
     upload_77e40c1d9a779cd78e3dd99f67e041c7
     upload_77e40c1d9a779cd78e3dd99f67e041c7
```

Thanks
Phil